# My segue is loading my UIViewController, before the last line adds data to it

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

This error occurred, after I added an extra segue to my UITableView. So that instead of the segue coming from a tableViewCell to my UIViewController, it now comes from the UITableViewController to 2 different UIViewControllers.

I set unique identifiers for both segues `showVerse` and `showAbout` .

The code in my UITableView looks like so :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if ( indexPath.section == 4 ) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showAbout", sender: self)
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerse", sender: self)
    }   
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {   
    if segue.identifier == "showVerse" {
        let pageDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PageViewController

        // Get the cell that generated this segue.
        if let selectedCell = sender as? PageTableViewCell { 
          //  ^~~~~~ This line loads my PageViewController for some reason 
          // Then my PageViewController fails because it doesn't have a `.page`

            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedCell)!
            let verse     = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].verse

            for page in pages {
                if page.valueForKey("chapter") as! Int == indexPath.section + 1 && page.valueForKey("verse") as! Int == verse {


                    pageDetailViewController.page = page
                  //    ^~~~~ If it could get to this line, then it would have loaded correctly.


                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        segue.destinationViewController as! AboutController
    }

}
```

When my `indexPath.section` is 0 - 3, it loads my PageViewController before a `.page` is assigned to it.

When my segue is from UITableViewCell to UIViewController, I don't have this issue. It seems to wait all my lines of code to run. And then it would know when my `.page` was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think sender should be self in your performSegueWithIdentifier methods.

I would do something along these lines:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if ( indexPath.section == 4 ) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showAbout", sender: cell)
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerse", sender: cell)
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method is sending `self` as the `sender` parameter to `performSegueWithIdentifier:`, but you are trying to cast `sender` as a `PageTableViewCell` in `prepareForSegue:` which will fail because `sender` is a view controller.

You should send your cell as the `sender` when you perform your segue.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if ( indexPath.section == 4 ) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showAbout", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
    } else {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerse", sender: tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath))
    }   
}
```